How to send PHP Email Using PHP Mailer (Beginner, New to PHP)
Firstly, I should mention that I am a brand new beginner to PHP and have no idea what I'm doing with PHP mailer or how to implement it.
So far, I've downloaded the PHP mailer snippet from GitHub and uploaded this to my Cpanel which looks something like this:

I am then trying to send a html email using PHP mailer using the following PHP script:
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


So far Nothing is happening, I get no errors and no email is being sent. I could really use some guidance on this to know where I am going wrong and to get this to work please.

mail() is not using PHPMailer.

None of the files in upper-case in that picture are actually part of the code, you can delete those.

Did you follow the install instructions from the official documentation (Installation & loading)? ? Because it seems you stopped after you downloaded the files, and then randomly started using some other code sample which, as brombeer says, has nothing to do with PHPMailer at all.

A simple example of using PHPMailer

For PC (Windows OS) or some OS. It's will block by default by firewall. You must manually add except rule for firewall to use your mail application.

Your current code uses the normal mail() function in PHP that will probably use the STMP server your web server is configured with. The email was probably sent, but the receiving mail server rejected it. This can happen if you used an email address from any of the big tech companies and the mail server you use hasn't been tweaked to a state that its emails are acceptable to big tech.

@JakkapongRattananen OP mentioned cPanel so this will be on a hosted server, not their local PC

Here's a good general guide to debugging email problems in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/5947043. If you do end up actually using PHPMailer (which is certainly a good idea, it's a lot easier to get it right than while uising mail), it has its own very helpful debug mode and troubleshooting guide: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

@ADyson OP develop on virtual machine-like is also possible.

@JakkapongRattananen sure. But cPanel is commercial paid-for software designed to help manage servers at scale. I think the likelihood of someone who is a beginner installing it on their local machine or VM is pretty small, don't you?

@ADyson if they're intended yes. but the reason that we can't send on new installed server isn't possible to come from firewall?

@JakkapongRattananen It's possible. But the OP won't be able to add their own firewall rule on a shared hosting system - they would have to contact the hosting service's helpdesk. And it won't be running WIndows. And if they're using mail(), it'll probably push the mail to the local sendmail service of the hosted server anyway, so no firewall would be involved. Firewall probably won't be the issue in most cases, with that setup. More likely the mail is sent but is then dropped or marked as spam by the receiving mailserver. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/5947043
